# Returning google map markers with ajax always null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

EDIT: Actual error I'm getting from the network data:

[image]

"Invalid JSON primitive: position"

Code calling for it:

```
function AddMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
    });

    var x = marker.position;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("AddMarker", "Map")', // Map Controller, AddMarker Action
        data: JSON.stringify({ "position": x }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.done)
                alert("Marker added");
            else
                alert("MARKER FAILED");
        }
    });
    map.panTo(latLng);
}
```

The server side function using a view model posted below it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMarker(LatLngViewModel position)
{            
    if (position != null)
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    else
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class LatLngViewModel
{
    double latitude { get; set; }
    double longitude { get; set; }
}
```

I tried using with quotes and without on position, stringifying the result or returning it with toJSON().  Tried stitching the toSend together with various quotes etc.  At this point I have no idea what's causing it and I have no other solutions at hand.  Appreciate any help on resolving this and sending the bloody coordinates back to bind them to the model somehow.

Comment: Which server side language do you use?

Comment: It's C#, using ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an object with latitude and longitude properties to match your view model. Like that:

```
function AddMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("AddMarker", "Map")', // Map Controller, AddMarker Action
        data: { 
            latitude: latLng.lat(), 
            longitude: latLng.lng() 
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.done)
                alert("Marker added");
            else
                alert("MARKER FAILED");
        }
    });

    map.panTo(latLng);
}
```

This is the important part that you were missing:

```
data: { 
    latitude: latLng.lat(), 
    longitude: latLng.lng() 
},
```

The `latLng` object that is passed to this function has 2 properties `lat` and `lng` which in turn are functions that you need to invoke in order to get the corresponding coordinates as decimal values.

---

UPDATE:

Make sure that your view model properties are **public**:

```
public class LatLngViewModel
{
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was already doing the function calls for both values,  and double checked the spelling.  Having removed the contentType and dataType did thankfully stop the error, however all data returned is now 0.  I tried setting values in the viewModel as float, double and decimal to no avail.

Comment: See my updated answer. The properties on your view model should be **public** or the model binder will ignore them.

Comment: Nailed it... and that's 4 hours of my time burnt right there on that single word.  Thanks again Darin.  I need to lie down a little now :P

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `JSON.stringify` to prepare the post-data.

Simply use :

```
data: { "position": latLng.toJSON()},
```

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind it?  I tried your recommendation, it's providing me with a 500 (Internal Server Error) now that I've changed it.

Comment: Last time I had this error, it's because they might contain circular references, which means I need to somehow eliminate any circular info and clean it up by sending just the long and latitude separately, not sure how to go on about doing that though..